# unable to mock restTemplate

Tags: spring, mockito

I would like to mock the following line:

```java
ResponseEntity<String> tokenHttpEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(builder.build(paramMap), requestHttpEntity , String.class);
```

And I try to do it by this:

```java
ResponseEntity<String> mockedResponse = new ResponseEntity<>(json, HttpStatus.OK);
Mockito.doReturn(mockedResponse).when(restTemplate.exchange(builder.build(paramMap), 
    HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers), String.class));
```

But when I launch my test, I get the following error:
[image]

Would anyone have an idea, please?

below the test class which use the service using resttemplate:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@Slf4j
public class EnergyWSConsumerTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

    public static final String       MOCKED_TOKEN_VALUE = "atoken";
    @Mock
    private             RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private EnergyWSConsumer energyWSConsumer;

    @Value("${energy.token.request.url}")
    private String tokenRequestUrl;

    @Value("${energy.api.url}")
    private String energyApiUrl;

    @Value("${energy.token.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${energy.token.password}")
    private String password;

    private UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder;

    private MultiValueMap<String, String> paramMap;

    private URI tokenURI;

    @Before
    public void beforeEach() {
        Mockito.spy(restTemplate);
        energyWSConsumer.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
        this.initAuthentificationMock();
    }

    @Test
    public void getEvementsRelevesTestCase() throws JSONException, IOException {
        Energy4BisRequest energy4BisRequest = new Energy4BisRequest();
        energy4BisRequest.setEndDate("2021-03-01");
        energy4BisRequest.setStartDate("2021-01-01");
        energy4BisRequest.setType("standard");
        energy4BisRequest.setOrganisationId("D00BPYN-01");
        energy4BisRequest.setDiCodes(List.of("D00DIIR-01"));
        initEvementsRelevesMock(energy4BisRequest);
        energyWSConsumer.getEvementsReleves(energy4BisRequest);
        Assert.assertEquals(MOCKED_TOKEN_VALUE, energyWSConsumer.getToken());
    }

    private void initEvementsRelevesMock(Energy4BisRequest energy4BisRequest) throws IOException {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> paramMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        paramMap.add("dateDebut", energy4BisRequest.getStartDate());
        paramMap.add("dateFin", energy4BisRequest.getEndDate());
        energy4BisRequest.getDiCodes().forEach(codeDi -> {
            paramMap.add("codeDI", codeDi);
        });

        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(energyApiUrl);

        // build the headers
        Map<String, String> headers = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + MOCKED_TOKEN_VALUE);


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String buffer;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(EnergyWSConsumerTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("energy-v1-evenements-releves-response.json").getFile()));
        while ((buffer = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(buffer);
        }
        br.close();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = StringUtils.normalizeSpace(sb.toString());
        EnergyV1ConsumptionReading[] energyV1ConsumptionReadingArray = objectMapper.readValue(json, EnergyV1ConsumptionReading[].class);

        ResponseEntity<String> mockedResponse = new ResponseEntity<>(json, HttpStatus.OK);
//      Mockito.doReturn(mockedResponse).when(restTemplate.exchange(builder.build(paramMap), HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers),
//              ResponseEntity.class));
        Mockito.doReturn(mockedResponse)
                .when(restTemplate.postForEntity(builder.build(paramMap), new HttpEntity<>(headers), String.class));
    }
}
```

the class tested:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@Data
public class EnergyWSConsumer {

    public static final String       AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";
    public static final String       ACCESS_TOKEN  = "access_token";
    @Autowired
    private             RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${energy.api.url}")
    private String energyApiUrl;

    @Value("${energy.token.request.url}")
    private String tokenRequestUrl;

    @Value("${energy.token.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${energy.token.password}")
    private String password;

    private String token;

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }


    public String getEvementsReleves(Energy4BisRequest energy4BisRequest) throws JSONException {
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(token)) {
            log.debug("Token must be generated");
            generateRemoteToken();
        }

        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(energyApiUrl);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> paramMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        paramMap.add("dateDebut", energy4BisRequest.getStartDate());
        paramMap.add("dateFin", energy4BisRequest.getEndDate());
        energy4BisRequest.getDiCodes().forEach(codeDi -> {
            paramMap.add("codeDI", codeDi);
        });

        Map<String, String> headers = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

        log.debug("GetEvementsReleves requesting: {}", builder.toUriString());
        HttpEntity<EnergyV1ConsumptionReading[]> energyV1ConsumptionReadingArrayEntity = restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers),
                EnergyV1ConsumptionReading[].class);

        log.info(energyV1ConsumptionReadingArrayEntity.toString());
        return null;
    }


    public void generateRemoteToken() throws JSONException {

        log.debug("Request for token generation");

        // build the url with params
        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(tokenRequestUrl);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> paramMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        paramMap.add("grant_type", "client_credentials");

        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setBasicAuth(username, password);
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> requestHttpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(paramMap, httpHeaders);

        log.error("GenerateRemoteTokenURI requesting: {}", builder.toUriString());

        ResponseEntity<String> tokenHttpEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(builder.build(paramMap), requestHttpEntity, String.class);

        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(tokenHttpEntity.getBody());
        if (response.has(ACCESS_TOKEN)) {
            this.token = response.getString(ACCESS_TOKEN);
            log.debug("Token generated");
        } else {
            log.warn("No token found in the oauth2 token response: {}", tokenHttpEntity.getBody());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know TestRestTemplate? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testresttemplate

Comment: no sorry isn't usefull, because no object can me stubbed as a return, and so, I can't use a TestRestTemplace, because my current RestTemplae is a mock provided and linked to an under service which is called after in the test (in order to the service have a mock instance of RestTemplate too), not a TestRestTemplate which doesn't inherit of RestTemplate

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: @tripleee tel stackoverflow a correct and easy to use, and non block posting with poor indication to fix the syntax problem

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `postForEntity()` but mocking `exchange()` method. Try the following:

```java
Mockito.doReturn(mockedResponse)
    .when(restTemplate.postForEntity(builder.build(paramMap), new HttpEntity<>(headers), String.class));
```

Nevertheless, the error seems to be unrelated to this, which makes me think that you have other issues elsewhere but that we can't tackle because you only shared a snippet of your code instead of everything relevant.

---

Replace `@Mock` with `@SpyBean` and then get rid of the line `Mockito.spy(restTemplate);` in your `beforeEach()` method as follows:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@Slf4j
public class EnergyWSConsumerTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

    public static final String MOCKED_TOKEN_VALUE = "atoken";
    
    @SpyBean
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    (...)

    @Before
    public void beforeEach() {
        Mockito.spy(restTemplate);
        energyWSConsumer.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
        this.initAuthentificationMock();
    }

    (...)
}
```

Comment: no sorry same thing, the exception occurred again

Comment: Then please add more code. The complete class you are trying to test and also your complete test class. Thanks.

Comment: done for the code

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it. Thanks!